# Google apps script (Gmail) to label emails sent but not received reply to

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I found this great script for automagically labelling emails that need a follow-up, slightly tweaked to show emails I have sent that haven't had a reply yet.

This currently works only for the current email account. I have a Gmail inbox that retrieves mail from 2 other email addresses, how might I also make this script apply to emails from them too?

https://www.gmass.co/blog/add-needs-reply-label

```js
function labelNeedsReply() {

  // Check to see if the label exists and create it if the label does not exist

  var labelCheck = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Needs Reply');
  if (labelCheck == null) {
    GmailApp.createLabel('Needs Reply');
  }

  // Go through threads in inbox or messages elsewhere with the needs-reply label to see if they still need it

  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox OR label:needs-reply');
  var currentUserEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var needsReplyLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Needs Reply');

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var lastMessage = threads[i].getMessages()[threads[i].getMessageCount() - 1];
    var lastMessageFrom = lastMessage.getFrom();
    if (lastMessageFrom.indexOf(currentUserEmail) != -1) {
      needsReplyLabel.addToThread(threads[i]);
    }
    else  {
      needsReplyLabel.removeFromThread(threads[i]);
    }
  }  
}
```

---

This line evaluates only for the current Gmail account, I just need to add two other clauses somehow e.g. "email1@domain.com" or "email2@domain.com" (or any email from @domain.com).

```js
if (lastMessageFrom.indexOf(currentUserEmail) != -1) {
```

Thanks!

I'm completely new to Google scripts so not sure what object/value I need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know which are the two email addresses and those are fixed.

I see two simple ways to do it :-

**Solution 1:**
You can do it using Else If clause. Let's assume the other two email addresses are test1@gmail.com and test2@gmail.com. Modifiy your IF ELSE part of code in this way.

```
if (lastMessageFrom.indexOf(currentUserEmail) != -1) {
  needsReplyLabel.addToThread(threads[i]);
}
else if(lastMessageFrom.indexOf("test1@gmail.com") != -1) {
  needsReplyLabel.addToThread(threads[i]);
}
else if(lastMessageFrom.indexOf("test2@gmail.com") != -1) {
  needsReplyLabel.addToThread(threads[i]);
}
else  {
  needsReplyLabel.removeFromThread(threads[i]);
}
```

**Solution2:**
Using OR "||" in the same IF condition if what you wan't to inside the IF is same for all three email addresses.

```
if (lastMessageFrom.indexOf(currentUserEmail) != -1 || lastMessageFrom.indexOf("test1@gmail.com") != -1 || lastMessageFrom.indexOf("test2@gmail.com") != -1) {
  needsReplyLabel.addToThread(threads[i]);
}
else  {
  needsReplyLabel.removeFromThread(threads[i]);
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I assumed .indexOf was a numeric value/ID not the actual text email address. This works perfectly - thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked! Please accept the answer by checking the tick mark on the left.